# Making BIRT see sqljdbc_auth.dll when doing integrated security database connection

Tags: java, birt

I am using BIRT that needs to connect to a database using integrated security via a jdbc driver.  When my .jar file (imported into BIRT) tries to connect to the MSSQL database, I get the following error:  The driver is not configured for an integrated authentication...
My conclusion is that BIRT dimply does not see the sqljdbc_auth.dll file.

How do I make BIRT see sqljdbc_auth.dll library, other than just putting it into the BIRT's root folder?  Can I issue -djava.library.path = .... somewhere within BIRT RCP?

Thanks!!

Comment: BIRT is an eclipse rcp project, no? Do you have an eclipse.ini file?

Comment: yes, that is correct.  BIRT is an eclipse project.  I tried playing with eclipse.ini adding -djava.library.path...but that does not seem to solve my problem...

Comment: just as a follow up, the exact error says:
Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path.

So the obvious and natural solution is to declare the path via 
-Djava.libarary.path = c:/the path /...dll.  But that does not seem to work

Comment: -Djava.library.path=c:\thepath\
The path should point to the dir containing the dll, not the dll itself.

Comment: @greyfairer, I absolutely agree with you!!  this is exactly what I did and it does NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the eclipse.ini? Any vm arguments should be put after the -vmargs option on a new line. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini.

Comment: Hello @greyfairer.  Thanks for looking into this.  Here is my .ini file.  Let me know if there is anything wrong with it. 
Thanks!!! 
 
`-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-DJava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86\"
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
`

Comment: -Djava.library.path=..., not -DJava.library.path=...

System properties are case sensitive.

Comment: I tried with -Djava.library.path=....
Unfortunately it still does not work...
I am getting the following error:
`Nov 07, 2012 9:45:23 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI <clinit>
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : no sqljdbc_auth in java.library.path`

The eclipse.ini has the following line now:
`
-vmargs
-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\auth\x86\"
`